# “unfortunately” after adding background xml

Tags: android

This error appears on certain applications
to help me fix it.

An error occurred when I added: `android:background="@drawable/gradient"`
I tried to seek help, but most of it was due to memory.

activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".TestActivity">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#69049B"
        android:endColor="#FD0EAD"/>
</shape>
```

error log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tamquoc.tamquocfull, PID: 4411
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tamquoc.tamquocfull/com.tamquoc.tamquocfull.TestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5307)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at
```

Comment: @Ty. Huynh Make sure your gradient.xml file is inside  drawable and not drawable-24.